# Lasso.py is not included in github.com/scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lasso-regression

I am trying to find Lasso.py on GitHub, I believe I should be able to find it at https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/main/sklearn/linear_model; but it is not there. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `Lasso` can be found in this file:

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bc07078b7653f1b704bc1b1bf2b43074f6f06215/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py#L808

You have to look in the __init__.py file when you want the details of a module.